# Regular expression to find a same consecutive words

Tags: regex

I'm a newbie to regular expressions and i have a problem in identifying the same consecutive words using regular expression. below is the scenario.

Here is the data :

```
;af;aj;am;an;ao;ap12;aq123;ar;as;ad;af1223;
```

and my current regular expression is `(;[a-z][a-z];)` and it only matches the below sets **;af;** , **;am;** , **;ao;** , **;ar;** , **;ad;** but my expectation is to match all these sets. **;af;aj;am;an;ao;** & **;ar;as;ad;.**

Could guys please guide me how to match these patterns?

Comment: How are they "the same"?

Comment: Use `*` operator or `+` operator. For example: `(;[a-z][a-z];)+` to match 1 or more sets

Comment: @Maciej, I think your pattern will not work because there is no double ";" (;;) in the data and your pattern only matches the first o"word" (";af;" in the data)

Comment: I agree with @nhahtdh -- What does mean "same consecutive words"? "af" and "aj" are not the same consecutive words.

Comment: @Jdamian indeed, my way of thinking was wrong. Sorry for causing confusion

Comment: @nhahtdh : sorry for confusion. What I meant was same consecutive patterns. Eg : ;[a-z][a-z]. It can be any chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your trying to extract the substrings which are in this `;[a-z][a-z];` format. If yes, then you could simply put your regex inside a lookahead to do a overlapping match.

```
(?=(;[a-z][a-z];))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
(;[a-z][a-z](?=;))
```

Try this.This returns the group you are looking for though its not clear how they are same.

The reason why urs was not working wass due to that fact (;[a-z][a-z]`;`) doesnt leave a `;` for the next element to start with.So it is not able to match as there is no `;` in front of it.A lookahead assertion doesnt cosume `;` thereby enabling all matches.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/4